# C/C++ file not compiling, (gcc not working) in Windows VScode

Tags: c, gcc, windows-11

I am facing this error whenever I click on the run button in VS code:

[image]

I used to receive this code whenever I ran it earlier and it works perfectly:

[image]

It asks me to select a debugger as given:

[image]

My code works perfectly fine when I use independent gcc commands but still here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr1[50] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int arr2[50] = {};
    int i, temp;
    int n = 8;
    int turn = n - 1;
    int sort = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] > arr1[i + 1]) {
            temp = arr1[i];
            arr1[i] = arr1[i + 1];
            arr1[i + 1] = temp;
            sort = 0;
            n--;
        }
        i++;
        if (i < n - 1) {
            turn--;
            if (!turn || sort) {
                break;
            }
            i = 0;
            sort = 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

For more info It occurs right after new VS code update was available Version 1.82
Please help me reset my settings or any other problem that I might be facing.

I have already reset code runner extension and checked all setting I have to, to use code runner:
[image]

Comment: The `cpp.exe` program is the C preprocessor. The C compiler driver program is named `gcc.exe`. You need to update your `tasks.json` file.

Comment: And in the future, please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: I recommend you read [the C++ plugin with MinGW documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). The code-runner plugin is just too simple for most needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few steps that worked :-

1. Restart the system (ofc works all the time).
2. Then I deleted the .vs code folder that had created some files due to unnecessary clicking on wrong option while selecting gcc.
3. Used a normal code with no errors any way possible, like a simple print statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Welcome");
}
```

4. Clicked the Run code on VS code.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gWzQ.png
5. Selected g++.exe option as given in the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVmQg.png
6. It worked successfully, now replace your code with the code you were trying earlier and it will work.
7. The terminal will run the given command by default considering the file name be world.c

```
cd "c:\Users\Varun Kharkwal\whatsoever your directory is\" ; if ($?) { gcc world.c -o world } ; if ($?) { .\world }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile directly from VSCode because the configuration file is invalid: `cpp.exe` is not the C compiler, but a C preprocessor that expects a single argument.  Furthemore, passing the full name of the source file including directory names with embedded spaces causes this program to receive multiple arguments.  The source file name must be surrounded by quotes to prevent the embedded spaces act as argument separators.

> My code works perfectly fine when I use independent gcc commands but still here is the code.

I'm afraid the code only works because the array is sorted already.

- you should not decrement `n` at each swap, but only when reaching the end of the array.  You combine a `sort` flag and a number of `turns`: a simpler approach for this type of sorting algorithm is to use nested loops and a single `sorted` flag.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr1[] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int n = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int last = n - 1;
    int sorted = 0;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] > arr1[i + 1]) {
                int temp = arr1[i];
                arr1[i] = arr1[i + 1];
                arr1[i + 1] = temp;
                sorted = 0;
            }
        }
        last = last - 1;  // the last element is the largest one
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I press Code rune button it used to run this type of command, I want the same to continue when I press it, I already know the code is incomplete, I just want.          
cd "c:\Users\Varun Kharkwal\Desktop\Programmer's Space\C++ with Varun Kharkwal\" ; if ($?) { g++ Excel_Sheet_Column_Title.cpp -o Excel_Sheet_Column_Title } ; if ($?) { .\Excel_Sheet_Column_Title }

Comment: @VARUNKHARKWAL: your code is written in C, use `gcc` instead of `g++`.  Regarding the VSCode configuration, I invite other contributors who know this environment and OS post appropriate solutions.